# Odd Mysql issue on insert

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Hy all,

Not sure what's going on here, but if I run this:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO users 
(`id`, `first_name`, `second_name`, `register_date`, `lastlogin_date`) 
VALUES 
("'. $user_id . '", "' . $first_name .'", "'. $second_name . '", "' . $date . '", "' . $date . ");'; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I get no return, but if I change it to this it's fine:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `second_name`, `register_date`, `lastlogin_date`) 
VALUES ("21021212", "Joe", "Bloggs", "20090202", "20090202");'; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

User id = bigint(20)

first name = varchar(30)

second name = varchar(30)

date = int(8)

At first I thought it was a issue with the vars but they are exactly the same and still don't work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you print out $query, what does it contain?

Answer (score 6):

Get into the habit of escaping all database inputs with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)- really, you should use some kind of wrapper like [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [ADODb](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm) to help you do this, but here's how you might do it without:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO users ".
    "(id, first_name, second_name, register_date, lastlogin_date)".
    "VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
    mysql_real_escape_string($user_id),
    mysql_real_escape_string($first_name),
    mysql_real_escape_string($second_name),
    mysql_real_escape_string($date),
    mysql_real_escape_string($date));

 $result = mysql_query($query);
```

and also check for errors with [mysql_error](http://php.net/mysql_error)

```
 if (!$result)
 {
     echo "Error in $query: ".mysql_error();
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

What's the result from "mysql_error()"? Always check this, especially if something doesn't seem to be working.

Also, echo out $query to see what it really looks like. That could be telling.

Comment: +1 This is the best advice, in the spirit of "teach a man to fish!"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the value of `$date` was `"1111'); DELETE FROM users;"`?

Seriously though? The problem is that isn't how you interact with your database.  You shouldn't be passing in your data with your query.  You need to specify the query, the parameters for the query, and pass in the actual parameter values when you execute the query.  Anything else is inefficient, insecure and prone to bugs like the one you have.

By using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or something that supports parametrized queries, you'll find these kinds of issues go away because you are calling the database property.  It is also much more secure and can speed up the database.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `second_name`, `register_date`, `lastlogin_date`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)")
$sth->execute(array($user_id ,$first_name , $second_name , $date, $date ));
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to echoing the query and checking [`mysql_error()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_error) as @GoatRider suggests:

1. Are you escaping your data properly?  See [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)
2. You shouldn't end your queries with a semicolon when using [`mysql_query()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_query)

Answer (score 0):

in $query = 'INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `second_name`, `register_date`, `lastlogin_date`) VALUES ("'  . $user_id . '", "' . $first_name . '", "' . $second_name . '", "' . $date . '", "' . $date . '");
are u giving the correct date format?? it might be the issue. otherwise the syntax is all fine.