# Only certain text will insert into database

Tags: php, mysql

I created a simple script to insert text from a form into a database. For some reason though, some text just won't insert! If I copy text from lipsum.com it inserts fine. But sometimes when I type, it just wont insert, no matter how many times I try. Random words, and paragraphs will always insert, and other just won't!

here is my code for the form

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if(!$_SESSION['logged']){ 
header("Location: ../../System/login_page.php"); 
exit; 
} 
?>


<?php

require '../db_config.php';

$place_holder;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT alerts FROM alerts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;") or die     ("Could not make query");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $place_holder = $row['alerts'];
  }

  ?>


    <div class="row">
<br/>   <br/>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4 contact-form">
        <form id="alert" method="post" class="form" role="form" action="../alert.php">
        <textarea value='hello' class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="5"><?php echo $place_holder;?></textarea>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

here is my code for the action(alert.php)

```
<?php

require 'db_config.php';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO alerts (alerts) VALUES('$_POST[message]')");

?>
```

Comment: check the size of the column alerts in table and data type

Comment: **don't** wont work due to the quote

Comment: I am guessing it fails when your message contains the wrong number of '

Comment: It's probably because you're directly inserting the value so any time there is an apostrophe, everything goes to hell. [See here](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html)

Comment: Please do the world a favor and read about how to do database programming properly in PHP. The internet really doesn't need more opporunities for SQL injection than it already has. By the way, if you had bothered to check the error message with `mysql_error` you would have been able to answer your own question without asking it here.

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated.  Read up about mysqli and PDO.  And while you're at it, look into "prepared statements" or "parameterized queries" (which both of the non-crappy extensions support).  Were you using them, this wouldn't even have been an issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Odd Mysql issue on insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694763/odd-mysql-issue-on-insert)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data you're inserting is not being sanitized:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO alerts (alerts) VALUES('$_POST[message]')");
```

If `$_POST['message']` contains single-quotes, you'll have a SQL error.

Try the following using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

```
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO alerts (alerts) VALUES('$message')");
```

However, I'd suggest you switch to the [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) libraries to take advantage of prepared statements instead.

An example with MySQLi (modified from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)):

```
// Connect to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

// Prepare the statement
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO alerts (alerts) VALUES (?)"))) {
     echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

// Bind the values
if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['message'])) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

// execute the query
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) when inserting strings into SQL statements.  This will prevent from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as well as escape syntactical characters so they don't break your insert query.